# Keep Constant my defined custom Action Bar layout for multiple activites

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

For my application I made a custom `ActionBar` by defining `layout` and `icons`. That `ActionBar` Slides from both side. Now when i choose a option from `sliding menu`, I am navigated from current `activity` to next `activity` but in this `activity` I also want to show my that defined `ActionBar` with action as its working for previous `activity`. Please Help me .  My code is here...

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    mNav = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);

    mNav.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_left_simple);

    initialization();

    findViewById(R.id.acti_login_backImg).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mNav.toggleLeftDrawer();
                }
            });

    mNav.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_right_simple);

    findViewById(R.id.acti_dashboard_profileSlideImg).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mNav.toggleRightDrawer();
                }
            });
```

and my event Listeners  are

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    acti_dashboard_backToMapTxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    acti_dashboard_zoneTxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    acti_dashboard_historyTxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    acti_dashboard_settingTxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    acti_dashboard_profileTxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    acti_dashboard_newLooqiTxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    acti_dashboard_languageiTxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    acti_dashboard_unsubscribeTxt.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.acti_dashboard_backToMapTxt:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MAin DashBoard Activity",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.acti_dashboard_zoneTxt:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zone Activity",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.acti_dashboard_historyTxt:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "History Activity",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.acti_dashboard_settingTxt:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings Activity",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.acti_dashboard_profileTxt:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile Activity",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.acti_dashboard_newLooqiTxt:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add Looqi Activity",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.acti_dashboard_languageiTxt:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Language Activity",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.acti_dashboard_unsubscribeTxt:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout Activity",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent logout_intent = new Intent(ActivityDashBoard.this,
                ActivityLogOut.class);
        logout_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(logout_intent);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Multiple activity** :- You need to put and instantiate your actionBar always.  As ActionBar is a part of your activity. You can create a single xml layout for actionBar and use `include` tag in your `activity layout xml`.

**Another part**, If you want to make `actionBar` static then just use **one activity** and Create `fragment` for all your `slidingMenu's` options.

Comment: thank you praveen... I include that custom layout in every activity's xml and by instating i achieved

Comment: Now please answer my question . Have you any idea to how to make interactive info window in google map in android ? I am able to display info box on map but when i am trying to click on its window's component then no any event is occurring. Please share me link or any example if you have

Comment: just have on look on it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows